# How to work with Worker.class from the outside

Tags: java, android

I have a Worker class which work with WorkManager, and i can't take something from that class.
In my case it's implement LocationListener and in onLocationChange() method I get Location, so I need translate this location in any other class (in Activity exactly, but nvm).

Becouse class created inside PeriodicWorkRequest -> I don't have instance of it and can't interact with him.

How people interacting with kind of class like this?

MainActivity.java

```
public class WorkView extends AppCompatActivity
        implements WorkViewInterface, LocationPermissionInterface {
    private ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(mainBinding.getRoot());
    
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(new PeriodicWorkRequest
        .Builder(ForegroundWorker.class, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build());
   }
}
```

Worker.class

```
public class ForegroundWorker extends Worker
        implements LocationListener {
@Override
public Result doWork() {
     locationManager.requestSingleUpdate
          (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
          this, Looper.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
        passLocationSomewhere(location);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post all relevant code in order for us to be able to replicate the problem, and thus, be able to help you. Guessing is not an option in Stack Overflow but more importantly, guessing doesn't help you at all.

Comment: @hfontanez in my case nevermind which code I have in other classes, for example I have String latitude = "94.98989898" in Worker.class, that all. I just must pass it in some other class.

Comment: In your case, nevermind getting help. We can't tell you how to interact with a class we don't know anything about. It is funny to me how you come here asking for help and when we tell you the information we need in order to help you, your answer is _nevermind which code I have_. Good luck to you!

Comment: @hfontanez ok, this is the code

Comment: I am assuming this is for Android. Correct?